# addEventListener click is immediately disappearing after KeyPress

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

For some reason I can not get it to work, after clicking enter on the keyboard the new input shows up for less than a millisecond and then disappears

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Register Form with JavaScript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="regFname" placeholder="First name: ">
            <button>Register</button>
        </form>
        <p>Current Users</p>
        <ul></ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is the JavaScript

```
var inputFname = document.querySelector(".regFname");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function inputLength() {
    return inputFname.value.length;
}
function add() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputFname.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    inputFname.value = "";
}   
function addUserAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        add();
    }
}
function addUserAfterKeyPress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        add();
    }
}
button.addEventListener("click", addUserAfterClick);
inputFname.addEventListener("keypress", addUserAfterKeyPress);
```

Comment: Your `<button>` element is submitting the `<form>`.  Change it to `<button type=button>` to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `type="button"` in your html. If not specified it behaves as `type="submit"`

```js
var inputFname = document.querySelector(".regFname");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function inputLength() {
  return inputFname.value.length;
}

function addUser() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputFname.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    inputFname.value = "";
  }
}
button.addEventListener("click", addUser);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="regFname" placeholder="First name: ">
  <button type="button">Register</button>
</form>
<p>Current Users</p>
<ul></ul>
```